# Validating route parameters to be greater than zero in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, route-parameters

How can I validate {id} to be greater than zero in the following route?

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}/show', [PostController::class, 'show'])->whereNumber('id');
```

Comment: You could also do `posts/{post}/show`, then have `public function show(Post $post)` in your Controller, and navigating to `/posts/0/show` would be an automatic 404: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the [Laravel 9.x documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints), you should be able to do this:

```php
Route::get('/posts/{id}/show', [PostController::class, 'show'])
    ->where('id', '([1-9]+[0-9]*)');
```

You can see that regex works for `number >= 1`: https://regex101.com/r/MFxO2h/2

---

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/78cb588f9f391016632b3f96755c851a712a442f/src/Illuminate/Routing/CreatesRegularExpressionRouteConstraints.php#L37-L40), you can see that `whereNumber` is `number >= 0`, that is why `0` works.

---

As @TimLewis commented, you can also use [Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding), it will automatically try to check if a model you want exists with the parameter ID on the route.

In your case, let's assume `{id}` is a `Post`'s ID, so your Route would be like this:

```php
Route::get('/posts/{post}/show', [PostController::class, 'show']);
```

Then, your controller:

```php
public function show(Request $request, Post $post)
{
   // ...
}
```

If no `{post}` (id) matches a Post's ID, then `404`, else the controller correctly executes the methods `show`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your regex does not match with some ids. I tried 100, 1000, 10000,... and I got 404 error response.

Comment: @max256 that is true, I confused a `?` with `*`, check the answer again and try it out

Comment: yeah, it works now, but please note that we can not still use it to check ids because it could match numbers bigger than maximum size of INT and BIGINT. I wish laravel had some build-in methods for checking ids, like whereId() and whereBigIntId().

Comment: You can check if a model exists, I am not sure about what you are doing with that ID, but as @TimLewis mentioned, you can use [Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding). Check my updated answer about that, if it works, please mark the answer as correct